# Is it "stir fry", "stir-fry" or "stir-fried"

Tags: grammar

Could someone confirm if "[stir fry](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stir+fry)" and "[stir-fry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir-fry)" are interchangeable when used as a verb (according to The Free Dictionary and Merriam-Webster) and if "[stir-fry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/stir-fry)" and "[stir-fried](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stir-fried)" are interchangeable when used as an adjective (according to Collins and Dictionary)?

Thank you!

Comment: The adjective should always be hyphenated.  But, as an adjective (describing food), "stir-fry" and "stir-fried" mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: Their use as verbs aside, note that *stir fry* is almost always used as a **noun**, not an adjective. (1) I ate some **stir fry**. (2) I ate some **stir-fried** vegetables. The fact that Collins classifies it as an adjective is nonstandard, to say the least.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Your use in (2) is adjectival, and the adjectival use is completely common.

Comment: @TinfoilHat If you follow the Collins link (I specified Collins), it is classifying **stir-fry** (not **stir-fried**) as an adjective. That's not common at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Ah, I see what you're saying. However it's not uncommon to use a noun or verb form attributively (to function as an adjective): *stir-fry technique*. Whether or not that earns it a freestanding adjective classification is up to the particular dictionary.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Indeed. We can normally have *a stir-fry technique* and *stir-fried vegetables*, but not *a stir-fried technique* (beyond being used as an odd metaphor) or *stir-fry vegetables*. It depends on the specific context of the adjective. However, I would argue that in *stir-fry technique* it's the noun *stir fry* that's being used attributively, rather than a so-call proper adjective.

Comment: @JasonBassford: The OED only goes as far as calling *stir-fry* "the verb phrase used attributively." It doesn't call it an adjective.

Comment: But it’s “stir-fried rice” not “stir-fry rice” except on poorly translated menus...

Comment: @JasonBassford: Thanks for the useful conversation; I gave you a shout-out in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The verb forms *stir-fry* with a hyphen and *stir fry* without one are interchangeable. The choice is between you and your style guide or editor. Pick one and stick with it. 
For example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir-fry), the dictionary that *The Chicago Manual of Style* recommends, uses the hyphen—as does the OED.

Using the hyphen in the verb form is useful because its derivatives—the adjective and noun forms—will also always use a hyphen.

> *I stir-fry very day.* (intransitive verb)
>   *I stir-fry vegetables.* (transitive verb)
>   *I like stir-fried vegetables.* (attributive adjective)
>   *My vegetables are stir-fried.* (predicate adjective)
>   *I like stir-fry.* (noun)
>   *I like the stir-fry technique.* (attributive noun or attributive verb phrase—functions as adjective).

Compare that to the open, un-hyphenated verb form, where—depending on the style guide—the adjective and noun derivatives might be open or hyphenated. You might find a rule like this:

> *I like stir-fried vegetables.* (hyphenated in the attributive position)
>   *My vegetables are stir fried.* (open in the predicate position)

Things could get messy.

.

Are *stir-fry* and *stir-fried* interchangeable when used as adjectives? Not really. Though Collins and perhaps others classify *stir-fry* as an adjective, other dictionaries see *stir-fry* as a noun or verb form temporarily repurposed as an adjective.* Depending on the noun being modified and the position in the sentence, only certain combinations work.

> *I like stir-fried vegetables.*
>   *? I like stir-fry vegetables.* (odd)
>
> *I'll order the stir-fry plate.*
>   **I'll order the stir-fried plate.* (grammatical but incorrect meaning)
>
> *My vegetables are stir-fried.*
>   *? My vegetables are stir-fry.* (odd; in any case, *stir-fry* becomes a predicate nominative here)
>
> *I like the stir-fry technique.*
>   **I like the stir-fried technique.* (grammatical but incorrect meaning)

(Thank you to @JasonBassford for the discussion in the question comments.)

.

.

.

*The OED classifies *stir-fry* as a verb and a noun, but not an adjective. Used in front of a noun, it's a "verbal phrase used attributively."  *Stir-fried* is classified as an adjective.

> **stir-fry,** *v.*
>
> **1.**  *transitive.* Chiefly in Chinese cookery: to fry (meat, vegetables, etc.) rapidly on a  high heat, while stirring and tossing
>   them in the pan. Also *intransitive*.
>  <sub>1969   *Guardian* 16
>   July 16/4:  Stir-fry the vegetables.</sub>
>
> **2.**  The verbal phrase used *attributively.*
>  <sub>1981    J.
>   MANN *Funeral Sites* xii. 77: Ian..had spent some time making a
>   Chinese stir-fry dinner.</sub>
>
> DERIVATIVES
>
> **stir-fried** *adj.*
>  <sub>1981    *Sunday Tel.* 6 Dec. 13/5: Stir-fried shredded beef with bean sprouts and celery.</sub>
>
> **stir-frying**  *n.*
>  <sub>1980    *Redbook* Oct. 136/2: To save time and money in the kitchen, Denise does a lot of stir-frying and
>   uses a slow cooker.</sub>

And:

> **stir-fry,** *n.*
>   <sub>**Etymology**:  <  STIR-FRY *v.*</sub>
>
> Food or a dish prepared by stir-frying.
>  <sub>2013    *Self* Apr.
>   56 (caption): Head off soreness by chowing on stir-fry with a few
>   teaspoons of ginger.</sub>

<sub>Definition and examples source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://OED.com) (login required)</sub>